# ¿Cómo transformar los valores string de un marco de datos en valores numéricos?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pandas, dataframe

Me gustaria transformar una dataframe de respuesta en valores numéricos.

```
>>> df1['Intention_vote_2020'].unique()
array(['Je sais pour en 2020',
       'Je ne voterai pas en 2020',
       'Je vais voter en 2020 mais je ne sais toujours pas pour qui je voterai',
       'Je voterai blanc', nan], dtype=object)
```

Entonces intenté

- `ord(x)

```
    df1['ascii'] = [ord(x) for x in df1['Intention_vote_2020'].unique()]
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-820471587e47> in <module>
      1 df1 = df
----> 2 df1['ascii'] = [ord(x) for x in df1['Intention_vote_2021'].unique()]

<ipython-input-31-820471587e47> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 df1 = df
----> 2 df1['ascii'] = [ord(x) for x in df1['Intention_vote_2020'].unique()]

TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 45 found
```

- `pd.to_numeric`

```
    df1['ascii'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Intention_vote_2020'])
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string "Je sais dÃ©jÃ  pour qui je vais voter en 2021"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-39ce2c8ed71f> in <module>
      1 df1 = df
----> 2 df1['ascii'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Intention_vote_2020'])

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\tools\numeric.py in to_numeric(arg, errors, downcast)
    148         try:
    149             values = lib.maybe_convert_numeric(
--> 150                 values, set(), coerce_numeric=coerce_numeric
    151             )
    152         except (ValueError, TypeError):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.maybe_convert_numeric()

ValueError: Unable to parse string "Je sais dÃ©jÃ  pour qui je vais voter en 2020" at position 0
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que *ord* recibe una cadena con un caracter y le estás pasando
cada cadena del dataframe.  Puedes usar:

```
[[ord(x) for x in s] for s in df1['Intention_vote_2020'].unique()]
```